# Jquery get id from class dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the value of a div class id?
I have this so far:

HTML

```
<div class="bolas-grad" id="<?php echo $list_titles[$zz]; ?>">
<?php 
$list_titles = array();
foreach( $list_posts as $post ) { 
$list_titles[] = $post->post_title; 
}

echo $list_titles[$zz];
?>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".bolas-grad").click(function() {
$(this).prop('id');
alert('id');
});
```

But instead of defining the 'id', how can i retreive the ID witch was clicked by the user?

Comment: `var id = this.id; alert(id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alert the ID, not the string `'id'`

```
$(".bolas-grad").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(id);
});
```